# Is there a way to force explicit parameter types in a constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, explicit

Is there anything similar to the explicit keyword for constructors in C#? It only seems to affect the cast operators in C#.

Take this example:

```
public Foo( long value )
{
    m_value = value;
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to make the following code fail to compile:

```
int bar = 10;
Foo fail = new Foo( bar );
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: Why? Int is passed by value, and the cast is implicit, so you are actually getting a long. What would it matter if the original value was an int? Why should compilation fail in your example? (By the way, as long as you are in value types, I think this is impossible).

Comment: What you're looking at here is to disable implicit casting from `int` to `long`, which I think is not possible.  The only way I could see it making a difference is if you have two overloads, one taking `int` and one taking `long`.  Do you have a use-case for wanting a compiler error?

Comment: There is no loss of precision going from `int` to `long` so *why* would you need a compile time error?

Comment: I want it to catch errors in the implementation. The particular class I'm using is used with serialization code that will be call ReadInt32 and ReadInt64 for a bit buffer. I want it to fail in the event that ReadInt32 is called since it means that the incorrect amount of bits will have been read, corrupting the rest of the read.

Comment: @TheChemist so in your implementation `long someValue = ReadInt32()` is valid?

Comment: Sounds like X-Y problem.

Comment: In C++ I would do something like explicit Foo( long value ), and that would disable implicit casts for all of the parameters.

Comment: @Matthew, yeah ReadInt32 returns an int, which can be implicitly cast to a long. I don't think there's any way to disable that.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but this is the wrong way of going about it. A function shouldn't care what its inputs are (as long as the casting is valid), and it certainly shouldn't care at compile time. Sounds like you need a function like "GetBits" that always calls "ReadInt64" and as a internal coding practice always call this function.

Answer (score 15):

You can cause a compiler error by adding an overload of the constructor that takes an `int`, and mark it as obsolete:

```
public class Foo {

  private long m_value;

  public Foo(long value) {
    m_value = value;
  }

  [Obsolete("The constructor has to be called with a long value, not an int value.", true)]
  public Foo(int value) {}

}
```

By specifying `true` as the second parameter for `Obsolete` it will cause a compiler error instead of the usual warning.

Comment: Of course, for this to work you would need to do one for every type that is implicitly castable to long, which there are probably quite a few...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Good point, but luckily you only need to overload some of the types. A `byte` for example would be converted to `int` rather than `long`, and would be caught in the right overload.

Comment: It would be a warning by default, isn't it ? The code wont "fail to compile"

Comment: @karim: By specifying `true` for the second parameter it will cause an error instead of a warning. (I just happened to clarify this in the question as you wrote the comment.)

Comment: Very creative.  Never would have thought of this.

Comment: I like this solution. It's true that it would need to be done for each value type, but it should be good for my limited usage. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

C# offers no equivalent to the C++ `explicit` keyword.
However you can create your own `Long` class where you enable only the conversions that you want (so here, do not define an implicit conversion operator to `int`).

```
public class MyLong
{
    public long Value { get; set; }

    // Declare here any wanted conversion operator
}
```

and then:

```
public Foo( MyLong mylong )
{
    m_value = mylong.Value;
}
```

This will fail to compile if called with an integer.

Comment: But that just moves the problem. You could still have `new MyLong() { Value = ReadInt32() };` which is wrong.

Comment: I don't see how this is any better since you can just as easily pass an int to the `Value` property.

Comment: It is better because it avoids implicit conversions. Which is the original SO concern. You can always find a way to explicitly do bad things, even in C#...

Comment: Other types could still create implicit conversions to `MyLong`.  `int` obviously isn't going to end up defining one, but other custom types could.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, I'm afraid that there isn't any equivalent in C# to the use of `explicit` on constructor parameters in C++, nothing that will cause a compiler error in the way that you want. As you note, the `explicit` keyword is only for use with cast operators.

`int` can be implicitly casted to `long` with no loss of precision, so it will be. I can't see any advantage to restricting the type in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

One (really obscure) way of accomplishing this is to have an overload taking an `int` and have the `Obsolete` attribute applied to it, and pass `true` for the `IsError` property.

```
public Foo(long value)
{
    m_value = value;
}

[Obsolete("Do not call this with ints", true)]
public Foo(int value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Usage

```
var x = new Foo(5); // gets error

var x = new Foo(5L); // no warning / error
```

However, as explained in the comments, this is probably a bad solution to a problem that could be solved a much better way.

I only answered this question to be pedantic about answering the question as requested.

Answer (score -7):

Have the constructor signature be for object instead of long, and then use typeof to see if the object was explicitly long.

Comment: Yes it will still compile but it may help the OP achieve the overall objective during runtime.

Comment: @RickDavin, you have it backwards -- it *will* compile, which is the problem.